# Node Integration Issue on Drupal8

Tags: node.js, socket.io, drupal-8

After some efforts the HTTP server started and status report showed that
node.js server was successfully reached. For testing my Drupal site I hit
a random url and waited for it to reflect on my dblog at the same time (as
demonstrated in the video). It failed. The backend showed the error - The
channel "watchdog_dblog" doesn't exist.

Here, the port used was 8888 (as per the video). It was changed to 8080
and then this error did not show up, but the drupal site still did not
auto-refresh.
The nodejs.config.js file currently:

```
 settings = {
      scheme: 'http',
      port: 8080,
      host: 'localhost',
      resource: '/socket.io',
      serviceKey: 'mytest1',
      backend: {
        port: 80,
        host: 'drupal8',
        scheme: 'http',
        basePath: '',
        messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
      },
      debug: true,
      sslKeyPath: '',
      sslCertPath: '',
      sslCAPath: '',
      baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
      publishUrl: 'publish',
      kickUserUrl: 'user/kick/:uid',
      logoutUserUrl: 'user/logout/:authtoken',
      addUserToChannelUrl: 'user/channel/add/:channel/:uid',
      removeUserFromChannelUrl: 'user/channel/remove/:channel/:uid',
      addChannelUrl: 'channel/add/:channel',
      removeChannelUrl: 'channel/remove/:channel',
      setUserPresenceListUrl: 'user/presence-list/:uid/:uidList',
      addAuthTokenToChannelUrl: 'authtoken/channel/add/:channel/:uid',
      removeAuthTokenFromChannelUrl: 'authtoken/channel/remove/:channel/:uid',
      toggleDebugUrl: 'debug/toggle',
      contentTokenUrl: 'content/token',
      publishMessageToContentChannelUrl: 'content/token/message',
      extensions: [],
      clientsCanWriteToChannels: true,
      clientsCanWriteToClients: true,
      transports: ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
      jsMinification: true,
      jsEtag: true,
      logLevel: 1
    };
```

```
I did not see socket.io while looking at the page source and inspect
element network. After that the node.js config module was enabled but the
service key field was non-editable. I then created a file nodejs.config.js
in modules/nodejs and copied the configuration there. Socket.io showed up
with the path localhost:8080//socket.io/socket.io.js. Even if I change the
port to 8888, the socket path/port remains the same.
```

This is the error now cleanupSocket: Cleaning up after socket id
C0I_r38wIbcT1LbtAAAD, uid undefined

[image: inspect element]

[image: inspect element socket.io]

[image: node js drupal setting]

[image: configuration builder]

[image: nodejs.config.js]

[image: module nodejs]

[image: module]

[image]